# Where I am Going Wrong With Typeahead.js Prefetch

Tags: javascript, php, json, typeahead.js, typeahead

I have been trying all week to get typeahead.js (https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) to work.

I can get the local version working, however I cannot get the prefetch working. I have a results.json file that is generated from a connection.php file. The JSON contains first_names and last_names. If I can get this simple methods to work I think I will have a better understanding of where I am going wrong.

I have included my files below.

### local method - working

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="countries"> 
<div class="demo">
<input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" placeholder="Countries" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" > 
<input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" disabled="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" style="visibility: hidden; ">
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var numbers;
var countries = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
limit: 10,
local: [
{ name: 'Andorra' },
{ name: 'United Arab Emirates' },
{ name: 'Afghanistan'},
{ name: 'Antigua and Barbuda'},
{ name: 'Anguilla'},
]
});

countries.initialize();

$('.countries .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
displayKey: 'name',
source: countries.ttAdapter()
});

});
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### prefetch method - not working

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/examples.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="names"> 
<div class="demo">
<input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" placeholder="names" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" > 
<input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" disabled="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" style="visibility: hidden; ">
</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**example.js**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var numbers;
var countries = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit: 10,
  prefetch: {
    url: './countries.json',
    filter: function(list) {
      return $.map(list, function(country) { return { name: country }; });
    }
  }
});

countries.initialize();

$('.countries .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'countries',
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: countries.ttAdapter()
});

});
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'myuser';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT first_name, last_name FROM actor';

mysql_select_db('mydb');

$return_arr = array();

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM actor"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
    $row_array['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($return_arr));


mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

My results.json file in in the following format if that helps;

```
[{"first_name":"PENELOPE","last_name":"GUINESS"},{"first_name":"NICK","last_name":"WAHLBERG"},{"fir...... ...
```

I appreciate any help or direction that anybody can lend, I am quite new to this and would like to learn as much as possible!

**update 1**
Following advice from @mgobi_php  I had a look at the chrome dev tools console and can see `"XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/dvd/countries.json"` So it seems like the json file is being recognised, but not loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe JSON file wasn't storing the data due to incorrect naming of displayKeys. Now fixed.